# InitializeComponent(); returns 0 reference in all user control files in C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm using VS 2019, I deleted one problematic user control file, and and name it the same name as the deleted one and it worked. But then all the other files, InitializeComponent(); returns 0 reference. I cleaned the solution and deleted all folders in bin and obj but it didn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace proj1
{
    public partial class uc_stock : UserControl
    {
        Connection conn = new Connection();


        public uc_stock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void bunifuLabel4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Assuming your UserControl is in `uc_stock.cs`, I'm guessing that `uc_stock.Designer.cs` has been deleted.

Comment: uc_stock.Designer.cs is there, but the code is too short than the way it was a week ago.

Comment: Hard to say, are you missing a namespace, which was present before?

Comment: Maybe. but in uc_stock.Designer.cs, protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) doesn't have any reference as well, so I think it can be one of the causes of the issue